# How to Get a single Value from php loop

Tags: php

I currently have a php script that loops content from MYSQL into smarty tpl file. basically html.. It gets the value from MYSQL and loops the rows fine. I also setup a Select link in the loop when click it toggles a dropdown form and submits fine. my question is, how can I get the ID of a single row when clicked on, put it into a hidden input within the form and submits into MYSQL on form submission.

my html code looks like this:

```
{section name=w loop=$test}
<tr>
<td class="menu1" align="center">{$test[w].ID}</td>
<td class="menu1" align="center">{$test[w].FIRST_NAME}</td>
<td class="menu1" align="center">{$test[w].LAST_NAME}</td>
<td class="menu1" align="center">{$test[w].GENDER}</td>
<td class="menu1" align="center"><a href="#" onclick="showOrderform('2');">Select</a></td>
{/section}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use jQuery .click() event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
<script>
$(function(){

$('a#select').click(function(){
id=$(this).attr("class");
$("input#select").val(id);
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code using jquery add the jquery file on top to run the below code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#select').click(function(){
var id= $(this).parent().first().html();    

});
});

</script>

<td class="menu1" align="center"><a href="#" id='select' onclick="showOrderform('2');">Select</a></td>
```

Comment: Hi MAK, thanks for your reply, I've also tried your method. how can I post the result to an input box? I am not that good with jquery.

Comment: to set the input box value below is the syntax: $(function () {
  $('#inputbox').val("text");
});

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with Javascript, because you want to retrieve the ID on the client-side, after the end of the loading of the page (when the server has already sent the page to the browser). So you can either:

- Modify your javascript call to add the ID : `onclick="showOrderform('2', '{$test[w].ID}');"`
- Or, use javascript onclick trigger to browse the DOM and get the relevant ID (here with jQuery, possible to do this without):

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

     $('#select').click(function(){
        var id= $(this).parent().first().html();
     });
   });
  ```

*Note:* Your `id="select"` should be `class="select"` since `id` should be *unique* in the page.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I really appreciate your help. so I am trying the first option, how do I get the id into a input box? I know how to post it, just not sure how to get it